# My incorrect answer for a TOEFL question

Tags: grammar

While I am training for my TOEFL exam using an Android mobile application, I found this question which seemed trivial to me but it turned out to be more complicated. Can somebody help me understand the grammar behind this answer because all what I could find using Google is what I already know:

> Before a person may drive a car on a public highway, it is necessary that he _____ a driving test.
>
> - take (the right answer)
> - is taking
> - took
> - takes (my answer)

Comment: You might want to Google "subjunctive mood".

Comment: This might help: https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=subjunctive%20mood

Comment: << It is essential that everyone attend the meeting. /  It is essential that everyone attends the meeting. / It is essential that everyone should attend the meeting. >> are all stated to be acceptable and equivalent in CGEL 11:7. This makes the insistence on the mandative subjunctive _take_ in the test question unwarranted; it would be rarely used in the UK. Some may argue that the mandative choice is better than the declarative on disambiguation grounds; I'd suggest that they should ditch both in favour of the _periphrastic should_ construction if they're sincere rather than prejudiced.

Comment: If you want to sound like a modern native speaker, use the inflected form ***takes***. If you need to pass one of those outdated language tests, use subjunctive ***take***.

Comment: This question is clearly based on American English. I thought the TOEFL was supposed to be unbiased. I would thus strongly suspect that this question would ***not*** actually appear on the TOEFL. Rather, I suspect an American wrote the Android mobile application you're using.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: if you want to sound like a modern native speaker of British English, use ***takes***. If you want to sound like a modern native speaker of American English from the Northeast, use ***take***.  (I can't vouch for other parts of the country. They use some strange grammar in places.)

Comment: They're all wrong, partly through violating Gricean maxims. 'Before a person may legally drive a car while alone on a public highway, it is necessary that he should pass a driving test.'

Comment: @Peter: I've said before that I think post-Webster AmE seems noticeably more conservative than BrE, despite the fact that *in general* Americans tend to think of anything that sounds [out]dated as being "British" (I suppose they think we're all still "Victorian" over here). But I bet even in the Northeast, the subjunctive is becoming less common in normal conversational contexts (not that OP's context falls into that category anyway; even Brits would probably still use the subjunctive in "formal, legal" contexts like that).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I hear the subjunctive all the time in normal conversational contexts. (Although I admit that sometimes people do use the indicative.)

Comment: @Peter: I have quite a few Indian neighbours who aren't native speakers of English. I'm not sure it would be correct to say they speak "Indian English" (as opposed to simply saying that they're not quite fluent native Anglophones in the UK context), but my gut feel is Indians don't use this "mandative subjunctive" so often as even Brits, let alone Americans. I'd be interested to know how this one plays out with *Chinese* learners, who I suspect will have a big influence on "International English" in the coming decades (I quite like many innovations originating in IE, but "CE" is an unknown).

Comment: *I agree that in some contexts it's necessary **that he use** the subjunctive, but it's tiresome **that he uses** it in other contexts where it's not needed.*

Comment: I enjoyed all comments and the information they have. Thank you all.

Comment: Is that question from a paper based TOEFL?

Comment: The worst method of learning language is learning grammar! BTW

Comment: The question is from a highly rated famous Android app and I don't the source of its questions